# Get value list from ManytoMany model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I would like to retrieve a list of values on the format `['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Audi']` (these are the three selected out from a list of 50+ different car makes made in a multiple select form field/list.

Values exist in a ManyToMany:

```
class CarMakeModel(models.Model):
    Make = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Product(models.Model):
    selection = models.ManyToManyField(CarMakeModel)
```

Now I would like to retrieve the selection made, e.g. in the shell:

```
select = product.models.Product.objects.latest('id').selection.values('Make')
```

This will return:

```
<QuerySet [{'Make': 'BMW'}, {'Make': 'Mercedes'}, 'Make': 'Audi'}]
```

How do I get this QuerySet reply into this format `['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Audi']` ?

I have tried `list(select)` and `tuple(select)` which returns:

```
[{'Make': 'BMW'}, {'Make': 'Mercedes'}, 'Make': 'Audi'}]
```

and

```
({'Make': 'BMW'}, {'Make': 'Mercedes'}, 'Make': 'Audi'})
```

but already now it feels I have taken too many steps for a seemingly simple request. My question is how do I more correct achieve my aim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `values_list` method instead:

```
select = product.models.Product.objects.latest('id').selection.values_list('Make', flat=True)
```